# OrientDB ETL from CSV DateTime

Tags: csv, orientdb, etl

This is currently my config file

```html
{
 "config": {
  "haltOnError": false
 },
 "source": {
  "file": {
   "path": "/home/user1/temp/real_user/user3.csv"
  }
 },
 "extractor": {
  "csv": {
   "columns": ["id", "name", "token", "username", "password", "created", "updated", "enabled", "is_admin", "is_banned", "userAvatar"],
   "columnsOnFirstLine": true
  },
  "field": {
   "fieldName": "created",
   "expression": "created.asDateTime()"
  }
 },
 "transformers": [{
  "vertex": {
   "class": "user"
  }
 }],
 "loader": {
  "orientdb": {
   "dbURL": "plocal:/home/user1/orientdb/real_user",
   "dbAutoCreateProperties": true,
   "dbType": "graph",
   "classes": [{
    "name": "user",
    "extends": "V"
   }],
   "indexes": [{
    "class": "user",
    "fields": ["id:long"],
    "type": "UNIQUE"
   }]
  }
 }
}
```

and my csv currently looks like this

```
6,Olivia Ong,2jkjkl54k5jklj5k4j5k4jkkkjjkj,\N,\N,2013-11-15 16:36:33,2013-11-15 16:36:33,1,0,\N,\N
7,Matthew,32kj4h3kjh44hjk3hk43hkhhkjhasd,\N,\N,2013-11-18 17:29:13,2013-11-15 16:36:33,1,0,\N,\N
```

I still wonder when I execute the ETL, orientdb wont recognize my datetime as datetime.

I tried putting datatype in column fields "created:datetime", but it ended up not showing any data.

I wonder what is the proper solution for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from next version, 2.2.8, you will be able to define different default pattern for date and datetime: [CSV extractor documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Extractor.html#csv-extractor)

Note that when you define the columns, you need to specify the column's type:

```
            "columns": ["id:string", "created:date", "updated:datetime"],
```

You can use the snapshot jar of 2.2.8 of ETL module  with 2.2.7 without any problem:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-etl/2.2.8-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Actually I did just that, the record won't show. So are you saying that this will only work using the 2.2.8 version of ETL? so my current 2.2.4 is currently not supported?

Comment: Note: 2.2.8 is still SNAPSHOT. On 2.2.4 there are some problems on date parsing. I fixed it, they will be in the 2.2.8. You can use the 2.2.8-SNAPSHOT jar with 2.2.4, it should works fine. My suggestion is to use the latest stable version, so 2.2.7 with 2.2.8-SNAPSHOT for ETL, till we release 2.2.8

Comment: Alrighty, so I just download orientdb-etl-2.2.8-20160822.044601-17.jar and put it on lib replacing the current 2.2.7 orientdb-etl.jar?

Comment: Yes. and reconfigure your ETL, of course.Let me know if it works.